# How to overwrite Files for Update Procedure

Tags: vb.net, updates, auto-update

I'm trying to create an updater for my app in VB.NET, No, I do not want to use clickonce, it sucks because I have to deal with managing self signed certs etc.

I know the code to check for new update files:

http://pastebin.com/ZjYBWABu

I also know the code for specifying where those files download to, the issue is I dont want to just download 1 .exe...I want to download all the latest build files which I would have uploaded to my server, which i would have taken from my Bin\release folder of my project.

Then when the updater downloads the files to a directory, it would go to the directory of the application, and somehow overwrite/replace all the files that have changed...maybe by using a hash or something?

I do not know how to proceed with this. What I do know is this.

The updater and the main app would have to be separate so that the updater could do the replacing while the app is closed so it doesn't get file in use errors. After the updater app has finished it would then start up the main app from the new exe.

Would appreciate help here thank you guys.

Comment: Uhh, so because you think you're having issues with self-signed certs, you're going down the path of re-writing all of this on your own ? What concrete issues do you have with certs ?

Comment: Lets just forget about click once. Would be greatful if you could help me in the question I asked

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If the updater knows where the app is installed and in some cases is running elevated it should be able to replace files.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project for which I have to implement a similar approach for updates. The project is lengthy, it would take some time to finish. But this is how I have planned to apply the updates:

1. There will be two main parts of the application **Launcher** (main application program) and **Updater** (To download files from server and replace them with the new ones and then launch the new file)
2. The application will have the option to manually check for update and also to check for update on startup.
3. If an update is available, it asks the user to apply the update now or later.
4. If the user selects to apply the update now then **Updater** application is **executed** in a separate process and then **Launcher** application is **closed** from within the code in Launcher. I have following approaches in my mind to launch another program from within first one and then exit:

   - Execute the Updater directly from within the Launcher using Process.Start
   - If that causes problem then as second approach launch command prompt from Process.Start, execute another program (Updater) from command prompt, close the command prompt and then exit the Launcher.
5. The Updater application then **downloads** all the relevant files from the server and upon completion **old application files are replaced** with the new ones.

   - Update availability information from server will include the new Version_No of application. For the purpose of providing all files for update, I will **compress (zip) all of them in a single file** named as Application.Version_No (as given by the server).
   - Upon download completion decompress (unzip) them to a folder named as the same Application.Version_No.
   - After decompressing all the files in this (Application.Version_No) folder will be copied to the Bin folder of application.
6. The new application **Launcher** file is **executed** in a separate process and **Updater** application is **closed** from within the code in Updater.

I have NOT yet tried this scenario as currently my focus is on completing the main application, but surely this must work.

**UPDATE:**

Another approach to check for updates is to use a **bootstrap like application startup**. It will be the main entry point of the program. Upon execution it will check for the updates and if there is none the Launcher is executed otherwise it will download the files, replace the old ones and then execute the new / updated Launcher.

For copying / overriding the files

- One approach is to include only those files in the compressed (zip) file which are required to be replaced with the old ones and then after the download completes, either directly decompress them to the Bin folder or decompress them to a designated folder and then copy all of them to the Bin folder.
- As another approach which seems somewhat lengthy, an additional helper file (XML, text or any other format) could be prepared for the download.

  - This helper file contains information of updated files like version number of each file, location where these are to be copied etc.
  - The files may be downloaded to a specific folder named as the new application version.
  - After downloading all the required files to a specific folder process each file mentioned in the helper file. Compare version of every old file with the new downloaded file. If it is latest then replace it in the folder mentioned in the helper file.
  - As another step in between all the downloads may be verified prior to copying and replacing.

Comment: My problem is i do not know how to code the overwriting

Comment: @UriahsVictor You may process the directory/folder of downloaded files in a loop and copy all of them to the Bin folder of application. For more details refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @UriahsVictor Alternatively you may also have a specific text file in downloads that contains information regarding source files and their destination folders. Read that file from code and implement using the method mentioned in previous comment

Comment: I know the logic I need to use, sadly I'm having trouble putting the code together, I have the code for downloading the file/files so far, I was thinking of downloading a zip also at this point I am still trying to figure out the copying and overwriting code.


In your app will you overwrite everything? Or will you use some kind of hash to see which files have changed?

Answer (score 0):

Built an updater that ships with a daemon. Main project here:

https://github.com/UVLabs/dotNetUpdatify

There should be a way to eliminate the use of the daemon, if i figure it out i will update.